# Ubuntu: gnome-open doesn't work for relative URL

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

If I type

```
gnome-open foo.pdf
```

it shows an error for me: `Error showing url: Operation not supported.` But if I give absolute path

```
gnome-open ~/what/ever/foo.pdf
```

it works fine.

Is this a known limitation or a bug?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think the command `xdg-open` can open relative URLs. Opening my Linux virtual machine right now.

Comment: Odd, something must be wrong with your system as `gnome-open` should work as it is used in your first example and does do so on my system.

Answer (score 3):

My comment was correct. If Ubuntu supports `xdg-open` (most distros do, but I haven't tested it), you can just do the following:

```
xdg-open foo.pdf
```

It also won't complain if you give it the full path.

```
xdg-open ~/what/ever/foo.pdf
```